# How to get standardized fitted values

Tags: r, linear-regression, standardized

I know how to get fitted values in r

```
fitted.values(object)
```

However I want to get standardized fitted values.
I get standardized coefficients using "lm.beta" package.

```
object1<-lm.beta(lm_object)
```

After that I use

```
fitted.values(object1)
```

But I can't get standardized predicted values.
I just get unstandardized predicted values.

How I get standardized fitted values in R?

If you know somthing, Please reply for me.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you try searching the web using the title of this question?

Comment: I searched my question and I got an answer in SPSS yesterday. Is it using scale(object) in r?? thanks for reply. I got confused in z-score and standardized-fitted value. Thanks a lot!